# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch URLS path seem to be correct

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I receive the error message:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'journalrep' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['reports/journalrep/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)\Z', 'reports/journalrep/\Z']

My urls.py contains:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='reports'),
    path('sumlist/', views.summary_list,name='sumlist'),
    path('overallsummary',views.overallsummary,name='overallsummary'),
    path('checkreg', views.checkreg, name='checkreg'),
    path('checkdet/<chkno>/', views.checkdet, name='checkdet'),
    path('journalrep/', views.journalrep, name='journalrep'),
    path('journalrep/<column>/<direction>', views.journalrep, name='journalrep'),
    path('journaldet/<tranid>', views.journaldet, name='journaldet'),
    path('accountrep', views.accountrep, name='accountrep')
]
```

The view that renders the template is a function view:

```
@login_required
def journalrep(request,column = 'date', direction = 'D'):
    '''
    Produce journal register
        Will display information for a chart of accounts account if provided.  If the value is 0 all
        journal entries will be shown
    '''


    #
    # Get list of accounts (Chart of acconts)  to be used for account selection box
    coa = ChartOfAccounts.objects.all().filter(COA_account__gt=0)

    coa_account = request.session.get('coa_account', None)

    if len(request.GET) != 0:
        coa_account = request.GET.get('coa_account')
    else:

        if coa_account == None:
            coa_account = '0'

 
    if direction == 'D':
        direction = '-'
    else:
        direction = ""

    if coa_account == '0':
        journal = Journal.objects.all().order_by(direction + column)   
    else:
        journal = Journal.objects.filter(account__COA_account = coa_account).order_by(direction + column)   


    context = { 'coa' : coa, 'journal' : journal , 'coa_account' : Decimal(coa_account)}
    
    request.session['coa_account'] = coa_account

    return render(request, 'reports/journal.html', context)
```

And the template that is rendered is:

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <h2>Journal Register</h2>

    <select name="coa_account" hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' row.transactionID %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
        <option value="0">All</option>
        {% for option in coa %}
            <option value="{{option.COA_account}}" 
                {% if option.COA_account == coa_account %} selected {% endif %}>
                {{option.COA_account_name}} 
                {% if option.COA_account_subgroup != "" %}
                    - {{option.COA_account_subgroup}}
                {%  endif %}    
            </option>
        {% endfor %}        
    </select>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Date <br>
                        <a hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' 'date' 'D' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                            <i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"> </i>
                        </a>
                        <a hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' 'date' 'A' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                            <i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-up"  ></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">Account<br>&nbsp;

                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">Description<br>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount<br>
                        <a hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' 'amount' 'D' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                            <i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-down"> </i>
                        </a>
                        <a hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' 'amount' 'A' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                            <i class="bi bi-sort-alpha-up"  ></i>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {% for row in journal %}
                <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#detail-">
                    <th scope="row"> 
                        {% if request.user.is_superuser %} 
                                <button hx-get="{% url 'journaldet' row.transactionID  %}" hx-target="#dialog" >
                                    <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
                                </button>    
                        {% else %}
                                &nbsp;    
                        {% endif %}        
                    </th>
                    <td>{{ row.date }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ row.account.COA_account}}<br>
                        {{ row.account.COA_account_name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ row.description }}
                        {% if row.transactionID != "" %}
                            <br>{{ row.transactionID}} 
                        {% endif %}    
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">${{ row.amount | floatformat:2 }}</td>

                </tr>

                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog" hx-target="this"></div>
</div>
<script>
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("modal"))

    htmx.on("htmx:afterSwap", (e) => {
    // Response targeting #dialog => show the modal
    if (e.detail.target.id == "dialog") {
        modal.show()
    }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
{% url 'journalrep' column='date' direction='D' %}
```

And also in urls.py:

```
path('journalrep/<str:column>/<str:direction>', views.journalrep, name='journalrep')
```

And potentially removing the line above this also as I'm not sure its required.

It's possible that django is arching the first one, but hard to say with the information provided.

Comment: Suggested changes were made.  For the initial view which has no sort I included 
`  <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' column='nosort' direction='nosort' %}" hx-`

 I still get this error:

 `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'journalrep' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reports/journalrep/(?P<column>[^/]+)/(?P<direction>[^/]+)/\\Z']
"GET /reports/journalrep/nosort/nosort/ HTTP/1.1" 500 146106
`

Answer (score 1):

In this line (line 3 of the template)

```
 <select name="coa_account" hx-get="{% url 'journalrep' row.transactionID %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
```

You are not, at that point, looping through rows, so the value `row.transactionID` is empty, creating the empty argument of the error.

Based on what occurs later and your urls.py , you are prabably also wanting to reference `journaldet` rather than `journaldep` for that URL structure to work.